# How to fetch routes from own REST API in React Native?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, react-native, express

So I am currently working on an app for my company. I am new to programming and I watched a react-native course and a nodeJs course. The question I have is how do I fetch the things I need from my Postgresql database?

For example I have a AuthScreen where I have a login button. I also have my database connected with node-postgres and I have a Routes file where I have GET calls that look like this:`app.get("/auth/user", db.getUsername);` so I have a path that I want to target and a method that in this example just querys the db and gets the names of the users. In my AuthScreen I just want to fetch-call this route when my button is clicked but I dont know what route to target.

Do I fetch from "http:localhost:3000/auth/user" or just from "/auth/user" or something else? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the path from where you have to consume your backend services will look like this: `http://{BASE_URL}/auth/user`. The {BASE_URL} will be URL or IP of the server you have hosted your backend service. If you want to consume your backend from your local system. You can use the BASE_URL as localhost:.  will be the port on which your service is running.

Comment: Thanks for your response I am struggling to get the right baseurl the database i am accessing is running on a docker webside its set up there for me to work with it / test it. When I put localhost or the IP from the database or the docker link I always get Network request failed do you have a clue why?

Comment: Can you share the content of DOCKERFILE and steps how you deployed

Comment: Sorry I cant share the file because its our database and I cant tell you how it is deployed because I dont know. I have my App listening on port 3000 so logically i have to go to "localhost:3000/auth/name" am I right? and also I now have a bug and my app is not working anymore.https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17530 so I somehow need to fix this first but ty for your help dude!

Comment: I fixed the bug where my app wouldnt start anymore but I am still getting the Network request failed error in my fetch call :/

Comment: because localhost was not working i tried the emulator IP: 10.0.2.2 and my Ip address in both cases it doenst throw me an error but the data is not displayed

Comment: I think I got it I had to get my IP address and add the port my app is running on!